# Date format filter using ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

Does there exist a format filter in ag-grid like this?

```
field : 'replacementPieceDesignation.replacementPiece.maxDate',
headerName  : "Date (max)",
cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy\'',`
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Use `valueFormatter`

Example (using moment):

`headerName: '...',
field: '...',
valueFormatter: (data) => moment(data.value).format('L')`

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that this question was eventually asked of the ag-grid author, and answered here:

https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/1029

The answer is: *such doesn't exist. if you want to format dates, either use cellFormatter or create your own cellRenderer for displaying dates.*

Comment: thank you for your answer, the question in github is mine, i have converted the date in java side